# How to check time field falls between current time in C# when stored in MSSQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have two `time(7)` fields in my database `startTime` and `endTime`

I retrieve them and store them:

```
private TimeSpan? _startTime
private TimeSpan? _endTime
```

If the `_startTime` field was equal to `10:00:00` and `_endTime` was equal to `13:00:00`. How can I check if the current time falls between the two (10am and 1pm)? Do I need to create `DateTime` with this time somehow?

Comment: Do you ever need a startTime which is later than your endTime, to handle situations where the time period falls across day boundaries? And are both of them meant to be inclusive, or exclusive, or an inclusive start time but an exclusive end time? The latter is likely to be the best plan, if you can still affect it. Finally, is this the local time on the system you're running it on, or the time in some specific time zone?

Comment: End time will alway be later than start time

Comment: What @JonSkeet meant was, is it possible that the start time will be 23:00:00 and the end time 01:00:00 on the next day? And in general IMO saving start and end times in the database is better with `datetime` instead of `time(7)`

Comment: No it will always be the same day. They will not span two different days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
private TimeSpan? _startTime
private TimeSpan? _endTime

public bool IsBetween(DateTime? now = null)
{
    if (_startTime == null || _endTime == null)
        return false;
    if (now == null)
        now = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;
    return _startTime <= currentTime && currentTime <= _endTime;
}
```

You can also just do this in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTimes
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CurrentTime TIME
    SET @CurrentTime = CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)

    SELECT
        t.*,
        CASE WHEN t.StartTime <= @CurrentTime AND @CurrentTime <= t.EndTime
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'IsBetween'
    FROM
        <MyTable> t

END
```

Comment: Hopefully the OP can make the end time exclusive... that makes it much easier to create abutting periods, where any given time is in exactly 0 or 1 time period.